# Direction Derviative, Different Results, Possible?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given:

\begin{equation*}
  f(x,y) = e^{xy}, \quad P=(1,1),\ \mathbf{v} = (-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2})
\end{equation*}

I am trying to calculate the directional derivative of $f$ in direction of $\mathbf{v}$.

My problem is, that when I apply two different ways of caculating the derivative I get different results. However I do not find a mistake in my calculation:

1) First approach:

\begin{align*}
  f(P) &= e^{1*1} = e \\
  P + t \mathbf{v} &= (1,1)^T +  (-\frac{t\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{t}{2})^T = (1 -\frac{t\sqrt{3}}{2}, 1 + \frac{t}{2})^T \\
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
  (1 -\frac{t\sqrt{3}}{2})(1 + \frac{t}{2}) = 1 + \frac{t}{2} - \frac{t \sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{t^2 \sqrt{3}}{4} 
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
  f(P + t \mathbf{v}) = e^{1 + \frac{t}{2} - \frac{t \sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{t^2 \sqrt{3}}{4} } \\
  \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(P + t \mathbf{v}) - f(P)}{t} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0 } \frac{e^{1 + \frac{t}{2} - \frac{t \sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{t^2 \sqrt{3}}{4} } - e}{t} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0 } \frac{0}{t} = 0
\end{align*}

2) Second approach:
The directional derivative should be equal to the Jacobian of $f$ at $P$ times $\mathbf{v}$:

\begin{align*}
  J(f) &= [ye^{xy}, xe^{xy}] \\
  J(f, P) &= [e, e] \\
  J(f, P) \mathbf{v} &= [e, e] (-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2})^T \\
  &= \frac{e}{2}(1 - \sqrt{3})
\end{align*}

However that is not equal to zero. I am inclined to believe that there is a mistake in my first approach, but the calculations seem correct.

Comment: $\lim_{t\to\ 0}\frac{f(t)}{t}$ is not $0$ just because $f(t)\to 0$. Keep the expression for $f(P+t\mathbf v)$ and use L’Hopital’s rule, which will agree with answer in your second approach

Comment: ok thx. want to make it an answer? Then I can upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that you've made a mistake here:

> $$(1 -\frac{t\sqrt{3}}{2})(1 + \frac{t}{2}) = 1 + \frac{t}{2} - \frac{t \sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{t^2 \sqrt{3}}{4} = \frac{2 +t(1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}(1+t)}{2})}{2}$$

If you distribute the $t$ in the last equation you get $1 + t/2 -t(\sqrt 3/4)-t^2(\sqrt 3/4)$ regardless I don't see the point of your last equality since $1 + \frac{t}{2} - \frac{t \sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{t^2 \sqrt{3}}{4}$ is perfectly fine to work with when taking a limit as $t \to 0.$

Your biggest mistake however comes from when you calculate the limit as $t \to 0$ of 
$$Q_t =  \frac{f(P+tv)-f(P)}{t} = \frac{\exp(1+ \frac t 2 - \frac{\sqrt3}{2}t - t^2 \frac{\sqrt 3}{4} ) - e}{t}.$$

It is correct that the numerator converges to $e- e = 0$ but this doesn't mean that $Q_t \to 0$ since the numerator also converges to $0$.

You can use l'hospital's rule to find this  limit. Taking the derivative of the numerator and denominator you get

$$ \frac{(1/2 - \sqrt 3/2 - t(\sqrt 3/2) )\exp(1+ \frac t 2 - \frac{\sqrt3}{2}t - t^2 \frac{\sqrt 3}{4})}{1}$$

which converges to $$\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right) e = \frac{e}{2}(1 - \sqrt 3).$$

Comment: many thx. I really appreciate your help.